# How to set up inverse search with Okular and Kile

Tags: editors, kile, srcltx, forward-inverse-search

The title pretty much sums it up.  I use the package srcltx in my documents.  I am running Ubuntu with Kile 2.1 and Okular 0.8.2 as a viewer.  I am pretty sure that inverse search should work, but I haven't been able to set it up.  How does one configure the viewer and editor to make this feature work?

Comment: I wish to add that (my version of) Okular (0.20.2) has to be in "browse" mode, not in "zoom" or "selection" mode, for inverse search to work. (For all like me who drove crazy because they wouldn't understand why the feature suddently didn't work anymore.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check this Ubuntu forums thread: [How can I do an inverse search between okular and kile?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1088573)

Here is a summary of the required steps (not tested):

- Setup inverse search from Okular:

  Settings -> Configure Okular .. -> Editor -> Editor dropdown: "custom text editor"

  command: `kile %f --line %l`
- Set up Kile to tell LaTeX to add source info, i.e., set LaTeX build tools from *Default* to *Modern*:

  Settings -> Configure kile -> Build -> LaTeX -> "Modern" in the dropdown menu
- Add a new forwardDVI configuration:

  Settings -> Configure kile -> Build -> forwardDVI

  then:

  1. "new..." button on the right
  2. choose a name
  3. put the full path to the perl script (see below) as the command (don't forget to escape, i.e., put a backslash in front of any spaces)
  4. put '%target' as Options (the single quotes are important)

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# kile2okular. (c) Ian Wood, 2010
# based on:
# kile2xdvi. (c) Juerg Wullschleger, 2009

if($ARGV[0] =~ m/file:(.*)#src:(\S*) (\S*)/){
$dviFile = $1;
$line = $2;
$sourceFile = $3;
$sourcePos = '--unique "'.$line.' '.$sourceFile.'"';
if($dviFile =~ m|.*/([^/]*.dvi)|){
$dviFile = $1;
}else{
print 'usage1: kile2xdvi <dvifile> or kile2xdvi "file:<dvifile>#src:<line> <sourcefile>"'."\n";
exit;
}
}else{
if((!$ARGV[0]) || ($ARGV[0] == "--help") || ($ARGV[0] == "-h")){
print 'usage2: kile2xdvi <dvifile> or kile2xdvi "file:<dvifile>#src:<line> <sourcefile>"'."\n";
exit;
}
$dviFile = $ARGV[0];
$sourcePos = '';
}
if (!(-e $dviFile)){
print "$dviFile: No such file.\n";
exit -1;
}

`okular --unique "$dviFile#src:$line$sourceFile"\n`;
exit;
```

Comment: It'd be great if you can provide a summary of what they found to eventually work. (The answer on the second page of that thread.) This is since (a) a summary can be much more readable and (b) just in case link-rot sets in and that thread disappears. I know this is Ubuntu we are talking about, but .... just in case.

Comment: I got it working with the above steps but without resorting to the script but using okular as the embedded viewer..

Comment: What about for PDFLaTeX?

Comment: @Alessandro C. You do the same thing for PDFLaTeX, just in the build environments choose PDFLaTeX to have the modern type. I also completely ignored the part about the perl script and it still works perfectly.

Comment: @Dom, Alessandro: I tried it with Kile 2.0.85 and Texlive 2009 in an up-to-date Kubuntu with Okular 0.11.2 and PDF inverse search with pdflatex doesn't work. I also left out the perl script part. DVI inverse search however works with okular.
Dom, what versions are you using?

Comment: @Turion: I'm using Okular version 0.12.2, Kile 2.0.85, all inside KDE version 4.6.2, I realise this is late, but hope it helps. Kile has default profiles for forwardPDF and forwardDVI, but make sure your compilation type is set to modern, whether you're using latex or pdflatex. Okular also has a default profile for using Kile as the text editor.

Answer (score 8):

I tried what was described here and it did not work. I found [this link from the University of Illinois](https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/cs523sp11/Inverse+and+Forward+Search+in+the+Kile+LaTeX+Editor) and their suggestions worked; I'm working in Fedora 17, in case it makes any difference. Here is what they suggest:

> 1. Open some LaTeX file in Kile
> 2. Open "Settings -> Configure Kile..."
> 3. Click "Tools -> Build -> LaTeX"
> 4. Select the "Modern" configuration
> 5. Set the options to -interaction=nonstopmode -src %source
> 6. Click "ForwardDVI" in the list
> 7. Select the "Embedded Viewer" configuration
> 8. Click OK
> 9. Click "LaTeX" in the build toolbar menu
> 10. Click "ForwardDVI" in the view toolbar menu
> 11. Open "Settings -> Configure Viewer..."
> 12. Click "Editor"
> 13. Select Kile as the editor
> 14. Click OK
> 15. Scroll to some interesting location in the document and hold down Shift while left-clicking on that location. It should jump to that
>       spot in the LaTeX source.
> 16. Scroll to some other location in the LaTeX source and click "ForwardDVI". It should jump to that location in the DVI.

Answer (score 1):

Okular to Kile navigation did not work for me on Ubuntu 14.04.1 in the above mentioned manner.

Then in Configure Kile --> Tools --> Build -->"Select a tool"
I selected all possible tools and where-ever Modern was available I chose it.

Then it worked. Otherwise I have been struggling for two two days, it did not work. I must have wasted about a couple of hours for this at-least.

Hope this post saves time for many other people.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. In my case, I could not get inverse search to work using any of the above suggestions while using latex. But it worked with pdflatex by choosing Modern configuration as Puneet suggested.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I guess this is meant as a comment?